# Using Regex VS jQuery Replace

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <input type=button class="foo abtn_1">
    <input type=button class="joe bbtn_2">
    <input type=button class="doe cbtn_2">
    <input type=button class="joe dbtn_1">
    <input type=button class="foo ebtn_2">
</div>
```

On click, **I want to get the first part of the class with the underscore and number.**

So from the *first input I would be getting: abtn*

Currently I use:

```
$('#foo input').on('click', function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('class')
                   .replace('foo','')
                   .replace('joe','')
                   .replace('doe','')
                   .replace('_1','')
                   .replace('_2','')

console.log(a);

});
```

I would imagine there should be a more robust and faster performance-wise way of doing this probably with Regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find the right part of the right class name directly without doing any replacements:

```
$('#foo input').on('click', function () {
    var match = this.className.match(/(^|\s)([^\s_]+)_\d(\s|$)/);
    if (match) {
        var item = match[2];
        // do what you want with item here
    }
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EDrvJ/

Here's the regex explained:

```
(^|\s)    Match starting with either the start of the string ^ or whitespace \s
([^\s_]+) After that, match any number of characters that are not whitespace and not underscore and capture this match
_\d       After that, match an underscore and any digit
(\s|$)    After that, match whitespace or the end of the string
```

The `(^|\s)` at the start and the `(\s|$)` end ensure that we are getting a whole class name match, not just a partial match.  The `|` symbol is OR in regex so we can match either a `^` or a `\s` with `(^|\s)`.

Comment: what is the need of `|` in `(^|\s)`, Please explain the Regex

Comment: I added explanation of the whole regex to my answer.  The `|` is a regex OR so `(^|\s)` says to match either the start of the string `^` OR whitespace `\s`.

Comment: @diEcho - I should add that doing it the way I've done prevents partial matches of class names and allows the class names to be in any order and any number of class names.

Answer (score 2):

It is not jquery replace, it is generic javascript string replace

With using regular expressions it could look like:

```
var a = $(this).attr('class').replace(/(foo|joe|doe|_1|_2)/g, '');
```

If you need something generic for

> I want to get the first part of the class with the underscore and number.

then use

```
var a = $(this).attr('class').match(/\b([^ _]+?)_\d/, '');
```

Comment: `var a = classes.replace(/.*?\b([a-z]+)_\d.*/, '$1');` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on [this test](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-regex-in-date-processing) I ll suggest you to use split() function and please correct the sentence **"I want to get the first part of the class with the underscore and number."** , you function is not doing what you have emphasized

Give that you need first part of the class **WITHOUT number and underscore** :

```
 $('#foo input').on('click', function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('class').split('_');
    console.log(a[0]);
   });
```